# EclipseLink cache usage with CheckCacheThenDatabase

Tags: jpa, caching, eclipselink

My scenario is similar to the following:

```
User a = ...; //has email pippo@gmail.com
em.remove(a);
...
User aUser = findUserByEmail("pippo@gmail.com");
```

where findUser queries the object using a named query marked as `CheckCacheThenDatabase`. Unfortunately, it returns the object (in removed status) and not null as expected.

So, why the L2 cache is not updated accordingly?

Comment: you mean you're still in the txn where the object is removed? if so then i'd say that is normal. If not, then it's not normal

Comment: yes, same transaction. But since the transaction is considered 'dirty' because of the em.remove(user), shouldn't the L2 cache be updated? If not, how can I force an update to the cache?

Comment: L2 cache should only ever be updated with committed objects. You expect another EntityManager that is started at that point to see uncommitted changes?